# Another solution approach to find if trailing zeros exist for each row id

Tags: r

The code below removes trailing zeros exist for each row id.

This question has been resolved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452882/delete-column-depending-on-the-date-and-code-you-choose. However, I wouldn't want to use a long pipeline as done, using `pivot_longer`. Is there any reasonable way to do this? The code that does this is `mat1`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
    
df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
               "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-02","2021-07-07","2021-07-07","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-09"),
       Code = c("FDE","ABC","ABC","ABC","CDE","FGE","ABC","CDE"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,5),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),
       DR08 = c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0),DR09 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR010 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR011 = c(4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
       DR012 = c(0,0,0,3,0,0,0,5),DR013 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0),DR014 = c(0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

> df1
       date1      date2 Code      Week DR1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR09 DR010 DR011 DR012 DR013 DR014
1 2021-06-28 2021-06-30  FDE Wednesday   4    4    4    9    5    5    2    2    0    0     0     4     0     0     0
2 2021-06-28 2021-06-30  ABC Wednesday   1    1    2    5    4    4    4    5    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
3 2021-06-28 2021-07-02  ABC    Friday   4    4    6    4    3    5    3    4    0    0     0     0     0     1     0
4 2021-06-28 2021-07-07  ABC Wednesday   3    3    7    3    3    3    3    4    1    0     0     0     3     0     0
5 2021-06-28 2021-07-07  CDE Wednesday   3    3    3    3    6    6    5    9    2    0     0     0     0     0     0
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  FGE    Friday   4    4    2    2    2    2    6    4    0    0     0     0     0     0     2
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  ABC    Friday   3    3    7    1    1    1    7    7    0    0     0     0     0     2     0
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  CDE    Friday   5    6    4    5    9    9    8    8    0    0     0     0     5     0     0



x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))

x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Code, DR1, ends_with("PV"))

med<-PV %>%
  group_by(Code,Week) %>%
  summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))

SPV<-df1%>%
  inner_join(med, by = c('Code', 'Week')) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                  get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(date1:Code, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())

dmda<-"2021-07-07"
CodeChosse<-"CDE"

mat1 <- df1 %>%
  filter(date2 == dmda, Code == CodeChosse) %>%
  select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
  mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
  filter(cs == 0) %>%
  pull(name)

(dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))

 SPV %>%
   filter(date2 == dmda, Code == CodeChosse) %>%
   select(-dropnames)


    date1      date2 Code DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV DR04_DR04_PV DR05_DR05_PV DR06_DR06_PV DR07_DR07_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-07-07  CDE            3            3            3            3            3            3            3
  DR08_DR08_PV
1            3
```